# Can I work out minimal polynomial of a matrix just by looking. For example ...

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix}3&1&0\\
0&3&1\\
0&0&3\end{bmatrix}$$

I know the characteristic polynomial is $(x-3)^3$ and this is also the minimal polynomial.

I know that $(x-3)$ is not the minimal polynomial, simply by inspection. $(x-3)^2$ however is not so obvious and I would need to test this.

Now is this the right way to do this or am I supposed to be able to just look at it's form and know that the minimal polynomial is $(x-3)^3$?

For example looking at
$$\begin{bmatrix}10 &0 &0  \\
0& 10 &0  \\
0 &0 &10\end{bmatrix}$$

I can see straight away $(x-10)$ is the minimal polynomial.

Comment: You need to start with the minimal factor and work your way up like you are doing. Although, once you have looked at a bunch of examples, you may be able to guess.

Comment: Note that your matrices are all in Jordan normal form, in which case the minimal polynomial is immediately clear.

Comment: @servaes Maybe the answer is really obvious but I'm not sure how I would tell.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of information that will help:

> Let $J$ be a matrix in Jordan canonical form, and let the characteristic polynomial of $J$ be $\prod_{k=1}^m(t - \lambda_k)^{n_k}$. Then $n_k$ is the size of *the largest Jordan block* associated with $\lambda_{k}$.

If you can, I suggest that you try to prove it.  A very nice consequence of this fact is that a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if $n_k = 1$ for each $\lambda_k$ in its minimal polynomial.